# OPEN GL: is this the right way of using VBO IBO and VAO

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, visual-studio-2012

I'm familiar with IBO, VBO and VAO, while passing vertices, uvs and normals in one buffer. Though there are cases, when it's a little bit difficult to combine them in one buffer.

Therefore I came up with this piece of code:

```
glGenBuffers(2, &iboID[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboID[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertInd.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &vertInd[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboID[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvInd.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &uvInd[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenBuffers(2, &vboID[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tempV.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &tempV[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tempUV.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &tempUV[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID[0]);
glBindVertexArray(vaoID[0]);    

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(_shader->attrib("vert"), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_shader->attrib("vert"));
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboID[0]);
outputError();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[1]);
glVertexAttribPointer(_shader->attrib("vertTexCoord"), 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_shader->attrib("vertTexCoord"));
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboID[1]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

So my question is : Is this the right way of doing this? (because at the moment I see nothing drawn to the screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to specify different element arrays (in separate IBOs), each for a vertex attribute. This is not going to work. Defining separate VBOs for each attribute is fine, but the GL can only have one element array, indexing **all** the currently enabled attribute arrays at the same time.